# How to show dialog box in the Google Apps Script itself?

Tags: google-apps-script

How to show dialog box in the Google Apps Script itself?

`ScriptApp` has no `getUi()` method.

Answer (score 1):

That's true `ScriptApp` has no `getUi()`.  You could use `Class Logger` or `Class console` but they don't include any way to interact with the "user". Another option is to publish a Web App in order to be able to use `Class HTMLService` to create your own user interface and use the corresponding link to run the latest code.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web